Show that $ Y_n = \frac{1}{n} \text{min} \{ |X_1|, |X_2|, \ldots, |X_n| \} $ converges in probability to $0$ as $ n \to \infty $
Let $ X_1, X_2, \ldots $ be a sequence of independent and identically distributed random variables. Show that
$$ 
Y_n = \frac{1}{n} \text{min} \{ |X_1|, |X_2|, \ldots, |X_n| \} 
$$
converges in probability to $0$ as $ n \to \infty $ if the expected value $ E[X_1] $ exists.

Attempt:
To show that $ Y_n $ converges in probability to $0$, we need to demonstrate that
$$ 
\lim_{n \to \infty} P(|Y_n - 0| > \epsilon) = 0 \quad \text{for every } \epsilon > 0.
$$
This translates to showing that:
$$ 
P\left( \frac{1}{n} \min \{ |X_1|, |X_2|, \ldots, |X_n| \} > \epsilon \right) \to 0 \text{ as } n \to \infty.
$$
We can reformulate the expression:
$$ 
P(Y_n > \epsilon) = P\left( \frac{1}{n} \min \{ |X_1|, |X_2|, \ldots, |X_n| \} > \epsilon \right) = P\left( \min \{ |X_1|, |X_2|, \ldots, |X_n| \} > n\epsilon \right).
$$
Since the $ X_i $ are iid, we obtain:
$$ 
P\left( \min \{ |X_1|, |X_2|, \ldots, |X_n| \} > n\epsilon \right) = P\left( |X_1| > n\epsilon \right)^n.
$$

First end argumentation:
Because $ E[|X_1|] < \infty $, we can apply Markov's inequality:
$$ 
P\left( |X_1| > n\epsilon \right) \leq \frac{E[|X_1|]}{n\epsilon}.
$$
Substituting this into our equation gives:
$$ 
P\left( \min \{ |X_1|, \ldots, |X_n| \} > n\epsilon \right) = P\left( |X_1| > n\epsilon \right)^n \leq \left( \frac{E[|X_1|]}{n\epsilon} \right)^n.
$$
Now we consider the limit:
$$ 
\left( \frac{E[|X_1|]}{n\epsilon} \right)^n = \left( \frac{1}{n} \right)^n \left( \frac{E[|X_1|]}{\epsilon} \right)^n.
$$
As $ n \to \infty $, $ \left( \frac{1}{n} \right)^n \to 0 $ . Therefore, we conclude that:
$$ 
P(Y_n > \epsilon) \to 0 \text{ as } n \to \infty.
$$

Second end argumentation (according to the comment section):
For sufficiently large $ n $, we know that:
$$
P(|X_1| \geq n \epsilon) < \frac{1}{2}.
$$
Thus, for large $ n $, the probability that all $ |X_i| $'s are at least $ n \epsilon $ is:
$$
P\left( \min\{|X_1|, |X_2|, \dots, |X_n|\} \geq n \epsilon \right) = P(|X_1| \geq n \epsilon)^n \leq \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^n.
$$
As $ n \to \infty $, $\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^n \to 0 $, and therefore:
$$ 
P(Y_n > \epsilon) \to 0 \text{ as } n \to \infty.
$$

I would like to ask if my argumentation makes sense or if it is correct.

Fundamentally wrong proof. $a_n \to 0$ does not imply that $a_n b_n \to 0$ for a general $(b_n)$. Does $(\frac   1n) ( n)$ tend to $0$?

For a valid proof just note that $P(|X_1|>n\epsilon) <\frac  1 2$ for $n$ sufficiently large.

@geetha290krm While the current proof is strictly stronger, calling the original proof "fundamentally wrong" is odd: it had a single error that would have been fixed by replacing the problematic step with "Let $n > \frac{E|X_1|}{2\epsilon}$ so that [...]".

@clementine1001 It would be good practice to (1) fix your original proof as I've hinted at in the above comment  and (2) compare the two proofs.  Do you see how one of them proves a stronger statement?

Correcting my first comment: I put the '2' in the wrong place.  It should have read $n > \frac{2 E|X_1|}{\epsilon}$

Thank you for the explanation! I still don't quite understand how to choose $n$ such that $P(|X_1| > n\epsilon) < \frac{1}{2}$. Could you please explain the reasoning behind picking $\frac{1}{2}$ specifically, and what we should be paying attention to when selecting this bound? Is this bound arbitrary, or is there something specific about $\frac{1}{2}$ that makes the argument work?

@clementine1001 There is nothing specific about $\frac{1}{2}$. Since you are given $E(|X_{1}|)<\infty$, use Markov's inequality to get $P(|X_{1}|>n\epsilon)\leq \frac{E(|X_{1}|}{n\epsilon}$ to find $n$ such that the RHS is lesser than $\frac{1}{2}$. You can find $n$ such that the RHS is lesser than $0.000000001$ if you want. Again, as I have already stated, $E(|X_{1}|)<\infty$ is not necessary, merely $P(|X_{1}|<\infty)=1$ is enough. In that case, see that $P(|X_{1}|>n\epsilon)\downarrow P(|X_{1}|=\infty)=0$. Thus find $n$ such that the LHS is less than $\frac{1}{2}$.

@clementine1001 In particular, for any fixed $\epsilon>0$, choose $N$ such that $N\geq \frac{2E(|X_{1}|)}{\epsilon}$. And then the Markov's Inequality shows you that $P(|X_{1}>n\epsilon)\leq \frac{E(|X_{1}|)}{n\epsilon}\leq \frac{1}{2}$ for all $n\geq N$. I have edited in these details in my answer.

You don't need $E(|X_{1}|)<\infty$. You just need $P(|X_{1}|<\infty)=1$ for $\frac{|X_{1}|}{n}\xrightarrow{a.s.}0 $. As $0\leq\frac{\min(|X_{1}|,...,|X_{n}|)}{n}\leq \frac{|X_{1}|}{n}$ the conclusion would follow immediately.
As $P(|X_{1}|<\infty)=1$, fix an $\omega\in\{|X_{1}|<\infty\}$ and see that $\frac{X_{1}(\omega)}{n}$ is just a real sequence of the form $\frac{c}{n}$ where the value of $c$ depends on $\omega$. Thus almost surely $\frac{|X_{1}|}{n}\to 0$. And almost sure convergence is stronger than convergence in Probability.
To see what magic $E(|X_{1}|)<\infty$ holds in secret, you need to see that something stronger is true. Assume that $X_{i}$'s are positive (since you are dealing with $|X_{i}|$ anyway)
Let $Z_{n}=\frac{\max(X_{1},...,X_{n})}{n}$. We can show that $Z_{n}$ converges to $0$ almost surely when $E(X_{1})<\infty$.
First just see that $P(|\frac{X_{n}}{n}|>\epsilon)=P(\frac{X_{n}}{\epsilon}>n)=P(X_{1}>n\epsilon)$
So $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(|\frac{X_{n}}{n}|>\epsilon)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(X_{1}>n\epsilon)<\infty$$ as $E(X_{1})<\infty$. (For a posititive random variable $Y$, $E(Y)<\infty\iff \sum_{n}P(Y>n)<\infty$).
Thus the Borel Cantelli Lemma tells you that $\frac{X_{n}}{n}\xrightarrow{a.s.}0$.
i.e. there exists $A\subseteq \Omega$ such that $P(A)=1$ and for all $\omega\in A$, $\frac{X_{n}(\omega)}{n}\to 0$.
So fix an $\omega\in A$. We'll show that $\frac{\max(X_{1}(\omega),X_{2}(\omega),...,X_{n}(\omega))}{n}\to 0$. As $\omega$ is arbitrary, this will show that $Z_{n}\xrightarrow{a.s.}0$.
So once you fix $\omega$, the sequence $a_{n}=X_{n}(\omega)$ satisfies $\frac{a_{n}}{n}\to 0$.
Let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary. There exists $N$ (depending only on $\epsilon$)  such that $n\geq N\implies \frac{a_{n}}{n}<\epsilon$ .
Now for $m=1,2,...,N$, find a $N'>N$ such that $\frac{a_{m}}{N'}\leq \epsilon$ for all $m=1,2,...,N$. (Note that $N'$ depends on $N$ and $\epsilon$, but as $N$ depends only on $\epsilon$, $N'$ also only depends on $\epsilon$.)
So for $n\geq N'$, you have $\frac{a_{k}}{n}\leq \frac{a_{k}}{N'}<\epsilon$ for all $k\leq N$ .
And for $n\geq k>N$, we have $\frac{a_{k}}{n}\leq \frac{a_{k}}{k}<\epsilon$ (as we assumed that $\frac{a_{n}}{n}<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq N$).
Thus for all $k=1,2,...,n$ we have $\frac{a_{k}}{n}<\epsilon$ for $n>N'$.
Thus for all $n>N'$, $$\frac{\max(a_{1},..,a_{n})}{n}<\epsilon$$.
Thus $\frac{\max(a_{1},..,a_{n})}{n}=\frac{\max(X_{1}(\omega),...,X_{n}(\omega))}{n}\to 0$. Thus $$\frac{\max(X_{1},...,X_{n})}{n}\xrightarrow{a.s.} 0$$
Your problem becomes trivial now as $\frac{\min(X_{1},...,X_{n})}{n}\leq \frac{\max(X_{1},...,X_{n})}{n} $. Note that very little probability was used and this is essentially a real analysis argument.
EDIT There is nothing specific about $\frac{1}{2}$. Since you are given $E(|X_{1}|)<\infty$, use Markov's inequality to get $P(|X_{1}|>n\epsilon)\leq \frac{E(|X_{1}|)}{n\epsilon}$ to find $n$ such that the RHS is lesser than $\frac{1}{2}$. You can find $n$ such that the RHS is lesser than $0.000000001$ if you want. In particular, for any fixed $\epsilon>0$, choose $N$ such that $N\geq \frac{2E(|X_{1}|)}{\epsilon}$. And then the Markov's Inequality shows you that $P(|X_{1}|>n\epsilon)\leq \frac{E(|X_{1}|)}{n\epsilon}\leq \frac{1}{2}$ for all $n\geq N$.
Again, as I have already stated, $E(|X_{1}|)<\infty$ is not necessary, merely $P(|X_{1}|<\infty)=1$ is enough. In that case, see that $P(|X_{1}|>n\epsilon)\downarrow P(|X_{1}|=\infty)=0$. Thus find $n$ such that the LHS is less than $\frac{1}{2}$. This is simply because $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\{X>n\epsilon\}=\{X=\infty\}$.

Thank you for your detailed answer! It's interesting to see the real analysis approach, but since this is for a probability class, I'm looking for a more probabilistic solution. I appreciate your perspective, though!

@clementine1001 The essence of Probability Theory is in realizing that Probability is another branch of analysis itself. What I have done here, can be written in Probability theoratic (or measure theoratic language in a giffy). $E(|X_{1}|)<\infty\implies \frac{|X_{n}|}{n}\xrightarrow{a.s.}0\implies\frac{\max(|X_{1}|,...,|X_{n}|)}{n}\xrightarrow{a.s.}0$. I have merely written the steps in more detail. In anycase, my answer was to emphasize that you don't need for the condition $E(|X_{1}|)<\infty$ for a simple conclusion like $\min(X_{1},...,X_{n})/n\to 0$ a.s.

It is trivial that for any finite random variable (i.e. $P(X<\infty)=1$), you must have $\frac{X}{n}\to 0$ a.s. and $\min(X_{1},...,X_{n})\leq X$. (regardless of whehter they are independent or identically distributed or not, the minimum will go to 0 as long as $X_{1}$ is a finite random variable) It's a very trivial conclusion. What you have done is completely fine though.
